# Using keyboard keys in syncfusion diagram in asp mvc application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, diagram, syncfusion

I'm using ej diagram of syncfusion in asp.net mvc program and I want to know is there any option to let me create a new node by hitting <kbd>enter</kbd> or any other key? I mean any keyboard keys that I can use for creating and editing diagram or any keyboard event handler that I implement this feature by myself?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your requirement, please use “Command Manager” which provides support to map/bind command execution with desired combination of key gestures.  Please refer the code snippet below which represents the creation of the node, when we press the Shift+C  key.

Code snippet:

```
DiagramProperties model = new DiagramProperties();
Dictionary<string, object> Commands = new Dictionary<string, object>()
 { 
  {                                
           //command name
           "createNode",
           //command definition
           new Command()
           {
               //Name of the method/command handler that is defined in scripts
               Execute = "execute", 
               //Gesture to define when the command is to be executed
               Gesture = new Gesture()
               {
                   //Combination of keys and modifier keys
                   Key = Keys.C, KeyModifiers = KeyModifiers.Shift
                }
            }
        }
        };
        model.CommandManager.Commands = Commands;

<script type="text/javascript">
   function execute(args) {
       //add the node
       $("#Diagram1").ejDiagram("instance").add({ name: "rect", width: 100, height: 100, offsetX: 200, offsetY: 200 })
     }
</script>
```